# How can I initiate YearMonth based on ZoneId and a given year and month?

Tags: java, datetime

I have the following method to calculate the length of a given month in seconds.

```
public static long getNumberOfSecondsInMonth(int year, int month) {

    int daysInMonth = YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth();
    return daysInMonth * HOURS_IN_DAY * SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR;
  }
```

***The problem is, this code does not consider the ZoneId for the Winter-Time and Spring-Time.***

So, is there anyways that I can include the `ZoneId` into the below line ?

```
YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth();
```

Point: I know, i can initialize the `YearMonth.now(ZoneId)`, but then it looks too much work to get the final answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Duration
.between( 
    YearMonth.of( year , month ).atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) , 
    YearMonth.of( year , month ).plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) 
)
.toSeconds()
```

## Details

You must determine the first moment of the month.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( year , month ) ;
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = firstOfMonth.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

And determine the first moment of the following month.

```
YearMonth followingMonth = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
LocalDate firstOfFollowingMonth = followingMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = firstOfFollowingMonth.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
long seconds = d.toSeconds() ;
```

You said:

> this code does not consider the ZoneId for the Winter-Time and Spring-Time.

Daylight Saving Time (DST) is not the only reason for clock anomalies. Politicians change the offset(s) used within their jurisdiction for various diplomatic, military, and political purposes. As programmers, we should *always* account for possible changes to the offset even in places not observing DST.

Comment: Am I right in thinking this needs to call `d.getSeconds()` to return the result the OP is looking for?

Comment: @mohammedkhan Yes.

Comment: @mohammedkhan Or just use `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between()`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Just seen your update. I think it should be `getSeconds()`, not `toSeconds()`.

Comment: @mohammedkhan It's been there since Java 9. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317186/5133585).

Comment: @Sweeper I see, thanks.

Comment: @mohammedkhan Same effect with both methods. The original `getSeconds` method was a poor design choice because it breaks encapsulation, as we really should not know about an internal member field of seconds. In Java 9, the `toSeconds` was added to be consistent with the other `to…` methods. So `toSeconds` is preferable, but `getSeconds` must be used on Java 8.